# Deleting a resource only if the DELETE request is by the resource's owner in django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using `django-tastypie` have a `CommentResource` in my `api.py`. I now want to restrict it's behaviour such that if a DELETE request is sent, the comment gets deleted only if the DELETE request is sent by the user who wrote this comment.

So, I have to override the method `delete_detail`. But the signature of this method seems different [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization) and [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#delete-detail), specifically the arguments that the method takes. One takes `self, object_list, bundle` while the other takes `self, request, **kwargs`. Please explain what these individual parameters mean and what signature should my method have along with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**1. `delete_detail(self, request, **kwargs)`**

```
Resource.delete_detail(self, request, **kwargs)
```

This method **destroys a single resource/object**.

It calls `obj_delete`. If the resource is deleted, it returns `HttpNoContent (204 No Content)`. If the resource did not exist, return `HttpNotFound (404 Not Found)`.

It has `request` as a argument and also a `kwargs` dictionary.

**2. `delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle)`:**

This is used when **implementing your own authorization class**.

This method takes two parameters, `object_list` & `bundle`.

`object_list` is the collection of objects being processed as part of the request. FILTERING & other restrictions to the set will have already been applied prior to this call.

`bundle` is the populated Bundle object for the request.

As per the docs,

> In the case of the *_detail methods, you’ll have access to the
>   object_list (so you know if a given object fits within the overall
>   set), BUT you’ll want to be inspecting bundle.obj & either returning
>   True if they should be allowed to continue or raising the Unauthorized
>   exception if not.
>
> Raising Unauthorized will cause a HTTP 401 error status code in the
>   response.

This method is used for authorization. Here, you will return `True` if it is authorized to continue else raise an exception.

**This is different from the former as there you are deleting an object/instance but here you are authorizing and verifying what someone can do with the resources in your API.**

Since in your own case, the comment gets deleted only if the `DELETE` request is sent by the user who wrote this comment you need to **use the 2nd method**. Users are authorized to delete only their comments and not of others. `object_list` here will be Comments of that user after filtering from all the comment objects.